# What is ArcGIS Pro .NET SDK?

Tags: arcobjects, .net, arcgis-pro-sdk

What is ArcGIS Pro .NET SDK ?

Can I code with ArcObjects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a replacement

ArcGIS Pro .NET SDK: The Road Ahead
–
SDK and API

No need for “external” **PIAs (primary interop assembly) like with Arcobjects.** Simply install ArcGIS Pro.

This is the fully fledged 64-bit version that will use more than 4GB of RAM for processing a long drawback of ESRI - welcome to the 21st century

Still limited

> At Final Release: No APIs for: Facility Network Network Analysis
> Labelling Data Reviewer APIs still undecided for: Data Management 3D
> Analysis (TIN, LAS) Layout ArcGIS Pro .NET SDK
>
> ArcGIS Pro API Workflows at 1.0, 1.1: 2D and 3D editing 2D and 3D Map
> interactions (author, query, time, visualize) Content management and
> sharing (online, portals, web maps) Fine grained APIs for Geometry and
> Geodatabase Leverage .Net language features and async patterns
>
> What is not supported in the API for Pro?:
>
> Custom data source and feature class extensions Custom extensions
> (edit, feature class, map) Custom Raster functions Custom GP functions
> Standalone “ArcEngine” applications ArcGIS Pro .NET SDK: The Road
> Ahead

source:
http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc14/tech-workshops/tw_725.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There are some more samples available here: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk
and some documentation here: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/beta/sdk